# "Hadamard" divergences for interacting theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime

When dealing with noninteracting theories on potentially-curved manifolds, one can define e.g. quadratic operators, which formally diverge, using the ``Hadamard" regularization procedure. One central result of the surrounding theory is that whatever divergences occur are a feature of the equation of motion and the background geometry, and not the specific quantum state.

Unfortunately the Hadamard elementary solution does not apply when interactions are added. I was wondering whether one can nevertheless trust that divergences are state-independent?